# Symfony 2 - non bundle library integration and location

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, autoload, symfony-2.8

I am all about the best practice of symfony 2 and I would like to integrate a php library into the project. Library is a non bundle, a simple php class with some methods.

My question just follows the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533608/symfony2-how-to-integrate-a-php-library-which-is-not-a-bundle), which DOES NOT have an accepted answer. Anyway from what I read here I decided to autoload the class, but have no idea where should I locate the php file.

Maybe `src/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/`? I really doubt it since library has no dependency of other services I have.

Should I create a directory like `src/MyBundle/Services/` or `src/MyBundle/Libraries/`?

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Even if the other question does not have an accepted answer, the most upvoted one is right, what you should warp it on is a service. Because that library is basically providing your application with a specific service to achieve something.

Comment: So I could locate it inside DependencyInjection directory?

Comment: Nope, inside a Service one: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by b.enoit.be create a service from the class.

**MyBundle/Service/MyServiceClass.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Service;

class MyService
{
...
}
```

**app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    app.my_service:
        class: MyBundle\Service\MyService
```

use it e.g. in a controller

**MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        ...

        // get the service from the container
        $yourService = $this->get('app.my_service');

        ...
    }
}
?>
```